# Fallo en ultimo ingrediente con ifs

Tags: java

tengo un problema en la elaboracion en la ultima receta habas con jamon cuando doy a ejectuar y pongo por ejemplo espacio o enter
habas 
jamon
me da error java y tendria que darme habas con jamon he probado con todo pero no doy con la tecla.
EDIT: Os dejo con el codigo completo ya que debe hacerse con scanner

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.ejercicio6;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author nicoc
 */
public class Ejercicio6 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca tres de los siguientes ingredientes");
    System.out.println("Tomate");
    System.out.println("Jamon");
    System.out.println("Aceite");
    System.out.println("Habas");
    System.out.println("Pulpo");
    System.out.println("Patatas");
    System.out.println("Chorizo");
    String ingrediente1 = sc.nextLine();
    String ingrediente2 = sc.nextLine();
    String ingrediente3 = sc.nextLine();
    if (ingrediente1.equals("Tomate") && ingrediente2.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente3.equals("Jamon")
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente2.equals("Tomate") && ingrediente3.equals("Jamon"))
            || ingrediente1.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente2.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente3.equals("Tomate")
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Tomate") && ingrediente2.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente3.equals("Aceite"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente2.equals("Tomate") && ingrediente3.equals("Aceite"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente2.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente3.equals("Tomate"))) {
        System.out.println("Gazpacho");

    } else if ((ingrediente1.equals("Pulpo") && ingrediente2.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente3.equals("Aceite"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente2.equals("Pulpo") && ingrediente3.equals("Aceite"))
            || ingrediente1.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente2.equals("Pulpo") && ingrediente3.equals("Patatas")
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Pulpo") && ingrediente2.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente3.equals("Patatas"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente2.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente3.equals("Pulpo"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente2.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente3.equals("Pulpo"))) {
        System.out.println("Pulpo a la gallega");
    } else if (ingrediente1.equals("Chorizo") && ingrediente2.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente3.equals("Aceite")
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Chorizo") && ingrediente2.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente3.equals("Patatas"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente2.equals("Chorizo") && ingrediente3.equals("Patatas"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente2.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente3.equals("Chorizo"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente2.equals("Chorizo") && ingrediente3.equals("Aceite"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Patatas") && ingrediente2.equals("Aceite") && ingrediente3.equals("Chorizo"))) {
        System.out.println("Zorza");
```

y esta es la parte que debo cambiar quiero que cuando pida el primer ingrediente se le de un enter o espacio en blanco luego habas y jamon y me dice que no hay receta

```
//ESTA MAL
    } else if (ingrediente1.equals("") && ingrediente2.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente3.equals("Habas")    
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente2.equals("Habas"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente2.equals("Habas"))
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Habas") && ingrediente2.equals("Jamon"))
            || ingrediente1.equals("") && ingrediente2.equals("Habas") && ingrediente3.equals("Jamon") 
            || (ingrediente1.equals("Jamon") && ingrediente2.equals("Habas"))) {
        System.out.println("Habas con Jamon");

    }else{


        System.out.println("No hay receta");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Estan mal todos los parentesis. Cada opcion and debe ir entre parentensis, y en tu codigo algunas estan bien y otras no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo que tienes es una colección de ingredientes, una forma más sencilla sería usar  una Collection. En este caso HashSet:

```
HashSet<String> ingredientes
```

Un set te permite almacenar tus ingredientes:

```
ingredientes.add(ingrediente1);
ingredientes.add(ingrediente2);
ingredientes.add(ingrediente3);
```

Una vez almacenados, puedes consultar si el set contiene los ingredientes de forma sencilla:

```
if (ingredientes.contains("Tomate") && ingredientes.contains("Aceite") 
  && ingredientes.contains("Jamon")) {
  System.out.println("Gazpacho");
}
```

HashSet tiene la ventaja de que las búsquedas son muy rápidas.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recetas {

  private static String ingrediente1;
  private static String ingrediente2;
  private static String ingrediente3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduzca tres de los siguientes ingredientes");
    System.out.println("Tomate");
    System.out.println("Jamon");
    System.out.println("Aceite");
    System.out.println("Habas");
    System.out.println("Pulpo");
    System.out.println("Patatas");
    System.out.println("Chorizo");

    String ingrediente1 = sc.nextLine();
    String ingrediente2 = sc.nextLine();
    String ingrediente3 = sc.nextLine();

    HashSet<String> ingredientes = new HashSet();
    ingredientes.add(ingrediente1);
    ingredientes.add(ingrediente2);
    ingredientes.add(ingrediente3);
    if (ingredientes.contains("Tomate") && ingredientes.contains("Aceite") && ingredientes.contains("Jamon")) {
      System.out.println("Gazpacho");
    }
    else if (ingredientes.contains("Jamon") && ingredientes.contains("Habas") && ingredientes.contains("")) {
      System.out.println("Habas con Jamon");
    }
    else if (ingredientes.contains("Pulpo") && ingredientes.contains("Patatas") && ingredientes.contains("Aceite")) {
      System.out.println("Pulpo a la gallega");
    }
    else if (ingredientes.contains("Chorizo") && ingredientes.contains("Patatas") && ingredientes.contains("Aceite")) {
      System.out.println("Zorza");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("No hay receta");
    } 
  }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Se debe hacer con Scanner, he dejado el codigo completo.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para incluir Scanner. Mira a ver si te sirve ahora.